# Redis em Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cache

Tenho um modelo de Item. Tem como guardar Item.all(Item::ActiveRecord_Relation) no Redis? Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
$redis = Redis::Namespace.new("suggestme", :redis => Redis.new)

$redis.set("itens", Item.all)
```

Mas quando eu dou:

```
$redis.get("itens")
```

Ele me retorna `"#<Item::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe399d6e550>"` que é uma String...

A ideia era guardar um Array de itens.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é você guardar o `.first` deste relation:

```
$redis = Redis::Namespace.new("suggestme", :redis => Redis.new)

$redis.set("itens", Item.where(true).first)
```